# Magento: Adding +/- quantity increment buttons in list.phtml

Tags: php, jquery, magento, button, increment

I've added some quantity increment buttons to my product list view page, I've added the code to list.phtml - The +/- buttons and quantity field show up but I just need to link it all in with the 'add to cart' button, because at the moment if you click 'add to cart' it still only adds 1 product. Could someone please advise me on how i could do this?

Here is the PHP:

```
<div class="quantity">
<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo  $this->getMinimalQty($_product) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>"  class="input-text qty"/>
</div> <!-- /.quantity -->
<p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span>  <span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span>
</button></p>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
jQuery("div.quantity").append('<input type="button" value="+" id="add1" class="plus"   />').prepend('<input type="button" value="-" id="minus1" class="minus" />');
    jQuery(".plus").click(function()
    {
        var currentVal = parseInt(jQuery(this).prev(".qty").val());

        if (!currentVal || currentVal=="" || currentVal == "NaN") currentVal = 0;

        jQuery(this).prev(".qty").val(currentVal + 1);
    });

    jQuery(".minus").click(function()
    {
        var currentVal = parseInt(jQuery(this).next(".qty").val());
        if (currentVal == "NaN") currentVal = 0;
        if (currentVal > 0)
        {
            jQuery(this).next(".qty").val(currentVal - 1);
        }
    });
    </script>
```

I just need to know how to get the script and the 'add to cart' button talking to each other so that when you press the quantity increment buttons and click on 'add to cart' it will add the number of products indicated within the quantity field to the shopping cart.

http://www.onlineshopz.co.uk/demo1/index.php/starters/meat.html This is the website with it on, the jQuery buttons add and remove the products in the quantity box, but when you click on 'add to cart' it still only adds one product to the shopping cart. I need to get the add to cart button to recognize what's in the quantity box.

Comment: your question is not clear does your jqyery code work? i mean when you click the +/- button does it correctly update values? or are you having the problems with doing that? and for something like a shopping cart system, better to seperate your logic and the presentation, gives a lot of support to debug

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your jQuery in a document ready

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // js here
});
</script>
```